# Is there a function in go for timing work

Tags: go, timer, fyne

Pretty much a Go newby
I want to write an work timing application in go probably using Fyne for the GUI
Cannot find clear info on what Go Code / Library / Mod to use for doing work timers
Add Timer, Start Timer Stop Timer etc
I've searched for time and timers etc but no examples I can find fit this specific use case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "Timer"? There is no universally understood definition of this word, and it has no real meaning in Go.

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic to timing work - just a simple capture of start & end time instances:

```
func logDuration(name string, start time.Time) {
    log.Printf("%q took %s", name, time.Since(start))
}
```

so, for example, to log the duration of function:

```
func x() {
    defer logDuration("x()", time.Now()) // "now" evaluated at start of x(), but defer not called until end of x()

    // do stuff
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/yxF4rCUny8l

Answer (score 0):

I do not think fyne has anything to work with time out of the box, and I'm not sure if it needs to have something like that.
You can easily implement everything you need using the time package from the standard library https://pkg.go.dev/time as it was done in one of the example apps from the fyne apps page https://gitlab.com/cchuster/speader/-/blob/main/main.go
Also, you can see how to work with timers here https://gobyexample.com/timers